# if else for custom $curauth-> field

Tags: author, author-template

So I have a custom field on the author page, where a user uploads a image which will be used as a background image on their author page. I've setup up everything except I'm not sure how to setup a conditional to display a default image when the user hasn't upload his/her own image.

The custom $curauth-> field is called user_banner.

So basically:

[if user_banner]

The image would be displayed here.

[else]

The default image would go here.

[end]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`get_queried_object_id`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/) to fetch the current user ID and [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to retrieve the banner should do the trick.

```
<?php
// somewhere in your theme's author.php

if ($img = get_user_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'user_banner', true)) {
   // they uploaded an image, use it
} else {
   // they did not upload the image, show the default
}
```